# Help proving ((a, b), (c, d)) ∈ R if and only if (a ≤ c Λ a + b ≤ c + d) is reflexive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I've been told by two sources now that it's obviously true and that it's enough to say that in proof. That seems wrong to me. Would someone help point me in the right direction of how to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show that $(a,b)$ is related to itself via the relation $R$, i.e. $\left((a,b), (a,b)\right) \in R$. So ask yourself what needs to be shown? Wouldn't we have to claim that $a \leq a$ and $a+b \leq a+b$? Of course these two inequalities are trivially true.

Comment: ok that makes sense, i get it now, thank you.